# How to sum over sheets that have same index in pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel data containing multiple sheets.
The data is hourly rainfall data value that have spatial index longitude in row and latitude in column.
[This is the excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRPZN.png)

I need to sum over all these sheets to get the daily rainfall data.
How could I do with pandas in python?

Comment: Load the sheets into a list of dataframes, concatenate them, then use groupby and sum.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict = pd.read_excel('myfile.xlsx', sheetname=None)`. This function gives you a dictionary of sheets that iterate by  `for sheet in dict.items()`. The rest is same as the solution that @cs95 has provided. Concat them inside the for loop and then group by lat/long.